# Difference between .pdf and *.pdf in gitignore

Tags: git, version-control

Does including `.pdf` in a .gitignore file indicate that a file literally named `.pdf` will be ignored while including `*.pdf` ignore any file that ends in that file ending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct!

Here is a small example:

```
$ git status 
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .pdf
    abc.pdf
    funny/pdf/abc.pdf
    pdf/.pdf
    pdf/abc.pdf
```

In .gitignore:

- `.pdf` literally ignores `.pdf` and `pdf/.pdf`
- `*.pdf` wildcard * ignores all files with suffix `.pdf` (all files in this example)
- `**/*.pdf` same as above
- `abc.pdf` ignores `abc.pdf`, `pdf/abc.pdf` and `funny/pdf/abc.pdf`
- `pdf/abc.pdf` ignores `pdf/abc.pdf`, but not `funny/pdf/abc.pdf`
- `# *.pdf` this is just a comment

To ignore all `*.pdf` files, but not `abc.pdf`, `pdf/abc.pdf` and `funny/pdf/abc.pdf`:

```
*.pdf
!abc.pdf
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. It seemed to be doing that in practice but I couldn't find it exactly spelled out.